# Is it possible to display the call "graph" of an ant extension-point?

Tags: ant

I have an extension-point defined in ant :

```
<extension-point name="foo"/>
```

A lot of tasks contribute to this point in several imported ant files :

```
<bindtargets targets="bar" extensionPoint="foo" />
```

However I'm kinda lost as to exactly which tasks are contributing. Is there a way to have ant report the tasks that would be triggered by a given extension point ? More generaly, is there a way to display the "call-graph" (or simply the list of dependencies) of an ant task ?

I tried using verbose options for ant (-v and such), with no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can try to debug the ANT process in your IDE using remote debugging by adding some parameters to ANT_OPTS (mine is set in ~/.profile):

> http://blog.dahanne.net/2010/06/03/debugging-any-java-application/

And profiling may help. I found project Antro on ANT Wiki...

> http://sourceforge.net/projects/antro

Maybe you can try it out. The project is said to be designed for ANT, which looks promising in solving your problem.

Also you can use Yourkit Java Profiler to do a CPU profiling. YJP can show the call graph of a java application, but I'm not sure if one can find out which are ANT targets.

The following document shows how to start a java application with YJP agent.

> http://www.yourkit.com/docs/95/help/agent.jsp

Answer (score 0):

I know of 2 ways to get this information:

1. You can get the effective target/extension-point invocation sequence from Ant's console logger.  To do this, place Ant's logging facility into verbose mode by passing `-verbose` on the command line to Ant.  There are two lines, one after the other, that dump to the console immediately before most targets as they are invoked in your build script:

   - A line that shows a summary of the targets in the call sequence starting with the text, `Build sequence for target(s) 'artifact' is [...]`.
   - A line showing the detailed call sequence (nested targets and `antcalls` included).  This line starts with the text, `Complete build sequence is [...]`. This listing considers, as much as reasonably possible, the evaluation of any `if` and `unless` attributes of each target listed at the point the line is logged to the console.

   Simply invoke your Ant build as you would normally with the -verbose option and your console should have the information you're looking for.
2. You can get a pictorial representation of the call sequence using a tool called [*Grand*](http://github.com/Ant-Grand).  However, it hasn't been updated for quite some time and thus doesn't support extension-points (which is what you're concerned with here).  It will interpret `antcall's`, `ant`, and `depend'encies`.  It doesn't evaluate the `if` and `unless` attributes but simply identifies potential execution sequence - more of a dependency hierarchy than an actual call graph.  The project is on Github so an update to support extension-points may not be too difficult.

   The graphic is rendered using *Graphviz*.

For an actual call sequence, use option 1.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty sloppy, but it works.  Ant is actually pretty easily scripted, and if you are using at least Java 6 (or it might be Java 7), javascript support is built in and thus can be used right out of the box.  This defines a task that will echo the dependencies of any target in call order:

```
<scriptdef name="listdepends" language="javascript">
    <attribute name="target"/>
    <![CDATA[
        var done = [];
        var echo = project.createTask("echo")
        function listdepend(t) {
            done.push(t.getName());
            var depends = t.getDependencies();
            while (depends.hasMoreElements()) {
                var t2 = depends.nextElement();
                if (done.indexOf(t2)==-1) listdepend(project.getTargets().get(t2));
            }
            echo.setMessage(t.getName());
            echo.perform();             
        }
        var t = attributes.get("target");
        if (t!=null) {
            var targ = project.getTargets().get(t);
            listdepend(targ);
        }
    ]]>
</scriptdef>
```

In your case, you can create a new target (or not) and call it like so:

```
    <target name="listfoo">
        <listdepends target="foo"/>
    </target>
```

As I said, this is somewhat sloppy.  It probably isn't very fast (although unless your target triggers thousands of others, it probably isn't noticeably slow).  It won't handle antcall tasks (although it could be modified to do so easily) or respond to if and unless attributes.  If dependencies nest too far, it may hit a recursion depth limit (but I doubt any project nest them deep enough).

The array is used to make sure that each dependency is listed once (ant would only run them once).